# MQ Accounting & Statistics - Can't disable

Tags: ibm-mq, mq

I have used MQ Accounting & Statistics many times without a problem, but recently enabled both in order to do some capacity planning.

I now find that on a particular queue manager, even though I have disabled them both, I still get messages generated to `SYSTEM.ADMIN.ACCOUNTING.QUEUE` and `SYSTEM.ADMIN.STATISTICS.QUEUE`.

I'm running MQ V8.0.0.3 and used the following commands to disable the features.

```
ALTER QMGR STATMQI(OFF)

ALTER QMGR STATQ(OFF)

ALTER QMGR STATCHL(OFF)

ALTER QMGR ACCTMQI(OFF)

ALTER QMGR ACCTQ(OFF)
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: What does a sample message look like - can you post an amqsbcg example (header and hex contents) please

Comment: At a guess, do any of your queues explicily have STATQ set to ON and not QMGR? dis q(*) where(STATQ ne qmgr)

Answer (score 1):

You should use NONE instead of OFF.

OFF works only if objects has "Queue Manager" value of monitoring attributes. 
Read Online Monitoring section: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.explorer.doc/e_properties_qmanager.htm